# Xcode 10 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code (EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY: unbound variable)

Tags: cocoapods, code-signing, xcode10, xcode10beta6

This error pops up when doing Project > Test

```
/Users/.../Project/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Target/Pods-TargetTests-frameworks.sh:
line 104: EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY: unbound variable
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

**How do I resolve "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" error when trying to test a project with cocoapods?**

Comment: Did you try Xcode 10 GM seed? Did you raise the issue on https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues? What is a minimal Podfile that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8000

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code/60090102#60090102

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This helped me

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
pod update
```

I've read [BugReport](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7708). Problem was similar to mine and it was fixed in 1.6.0.beta.1 (2018-08-16) ([changelog](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)).

**Updated**(thanks to [Cœur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033581/c%C5%93ur))

1.6.0 (2019-02-07) Was published

```
sudo gem update cocoapods
```

This should work now.

Comment: Yeah, this fixed it for me. Kind of ridiculous that we need to use the beta release to avoid this issue. Hopefully they'll get the next stable release out quickly

Comment: 1.6.0 stable was released two days ago: no need to install a beta version of CocoaPods anymore: `sudo gem update cocoapods` is enough now.

Comment: Before doing this laborious task try solution 3. Mines working for this. :)

Comment: This helps to ignore code signing for pods, but the code signing of the main mac app also needs to disable.

Answer (score 21):

I have facing the same issue, i believe this issue have something link to keychain access too (code signing problem), I go to keychain access unlock the login then lock it again fixed this issue. After uploading toOSMojave and Xcode 10 keychain need to reverify the password. (how i find this? while facing same issue and trying all available option, i think to generate certificate again, but while generating private key i found keychain login user name and password is wrong type of message- i lock and unlock again solved my problem). Note this process required your login pass phare.

How to fix:- short tip

```
Go to keychain access -> right click on login -> lock & unlock again 
-> clear Xcode project and make build again.
```

Comment: Locking and unlocking the keychain fixed it for me. Either way, this fixes the issue with the password verification prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Some Framework or SDK require Code Signing.

I done code signing and resolved the similar problem for me.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY: unbound variable
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I had the same problem after updating `BuildSettings` and `Podfile`

I just **restarted** Xcode and opened a **workspace** - `.xcworkspace` (not project - `.xcodeproj`)

[[Workspace vs Project]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236567/4770877)

Comment: Worked - I had the Project file open, not the Workspace... :/

Answer (score 1):

Go to pod folder and change the file as executable file. It works for me.

```
chmod +x filename
```

filename => your file name like "swiftlint"

Answer (score 1):

```
On the top of - Pods-yourProjectName-frameworks.sh

export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=""
export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME=""
export EXPANDED_PROVISIONING_PROFILE=""
```

this is an issue with pod update.

Comment: This worked for me on Xcode 12 beta 2 (Catalina) with Cocoapods v1.5.2 ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could solve it, by just renaming the  project. In my case this error was, because I had a `'` symbol in my project name.

Answer (score 1):

- Delete the `Pods` directory and the `Podfile.lock` file.
- Run `pod install` to re-create them from scratch.
- Clean the Xcode project.
- Build the Xcode project.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on an M1/Apple Silicon Mac, make sure you have your Excluded Architectures set up properly. I don't know why this is necessary, but here's how you do it:

1. Go to Build Settings
2. Make sure you view "All" (default is "Basic")
3. Expand "Excluded Architectures"
4. Under debug, select Any iOS Simulator SDK, and add a value for "arm64"

Do the above settings for each relevant target, in my case I have "Pods", "Project", and then the iOS target.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple`pod install` worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. It turns out that by switching between Xcode9 and Xcode10 sometimes it can happen that the command line tools used for building can be switched so I was trying to build it with 9.4 command line tool instead of 10 which caused the issue.

Going to preferences and setting the command line tool to the right one fixed the issue for me.

Another thing that helped me is to disable and enable iCloud again. (Not sure why.)

Answer (score 0):

Ive been dealing with this issue for a couple of days now. What did it for me was.
-Update cocoapods to the last version
-Update all pods
-Opening keychain access and delete the key made by xcode (with xcode closed)
-Opening Xcode will recreate a new key and will ask you for the password. 
-After this I cleaned and built and the application ran on my physical device.

I hope this is helpful since its a very annoying bug.!

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the mac helped me,not the xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Check the issue clearly, if it is related to swiftlint.yml then this hidden file must be present in your directory. If you are working on more than one module then you can copy and paste it from your other modules if any.

Answer (score 0):

nvm alias default 16.6.0 if you want it pegged to that specific version.

You can also do nvm alias default 16.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I tried many solutions but all in vain

Solution: I just do "Pod deintegrate" and then "pod install"  then my project is working perfectly.