# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code after adding firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, xcode10, xcode10beta6

I've got this error after I installed firebase podfile:

```
Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Guess The Code 2.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework'
```

I tried this: [Xcode 10 Beta 3: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174105/xcode-10-beta-3-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code) but nothing has changed. 
I also tried to install GoogleUtilities pod separately but the error remained. 
What can I do?

Podfile

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationUnity'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAppLovin'
pod 'SAConfettiView'
pod 'Firebase'
```

Xcode 10 beta 6
Swift 4.2

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
I set 'test target signing Team' and I resolved the problem.
[image]

Comment: This was the hint that solved my problem. Signing team was set correctly. The mysterious "nonzero exit code" error disappeared after I removed the signing team and then set it again.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be linked to keychain service. To solve open keychain lock the login and unclock it again by entering you mac passcode.

Comment: my keychain access > right click login > options are greyed out. any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone. I was having the same issue. Creating a brand new Xcode project. Installing the Firebase using pods. Adding the GoogleService-Info.plist to the project but it was failing on it. This might not solve your issue at all but you can develop locally while a more permanent solution shows up.

I found that the script Pods-[ProjectName]-frameworks.sh in the Pods > Targets Support Files > Pods-[ProjectName] > Pods-[ProjectName]-frameworks.sh is trying to re sign the files for the project and it can't retrieve the proper identity. I temporary solved this and I am able to code and run the code locally by commenting by adding the '#' character in the line in the script that goes:

code_sign_if_enabled "${destination}/$(basename "$1")"

Like I said this is just a temp solution until I dedicate time to look into it. At least I can keep coding now. I hope it helps someone.