# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code I

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting the below error

> /Users/user321/Desktop/MapForAppNewest/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-MapForAppNewest/Pods-MapForAppNewest-frameworks.sh: line
>   114: local: `=': not a valid identifier
>   /Users/user321/Desktop/MapForAppNewest/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MapForAppNewest/Pods-MapForAppNewest-frameworks.sh: line
>   114: local:
>
> `/Users/user321/Desktop/MapForAppNewest/Pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/dynamic/826E141E-8875-3C3B-A106-2B772F8A0684.bcsymbolmap':
>   not a valid identifier
>       Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I have found many similar questions but they all failed to address this specific problem and offer a solution which works here. So I ask **What is the problem here and how do I go about fixing it?** (im using Swift and Firebase)

Comment: Have you tried anything worth sharing? Maby show examples of what you have reasearched

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file - /Users/user321/Desktop/MapForAppNewest/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MapForAppNewest/Pods-MapForAppNewest-frameworks.sh
2. On line 114, delete the spacing before and after '='
3. Clean and build project

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by renaming of the folder name (the folder containing the project)

- I cloned my project 'hovermind' into 'Foo' folder
- Installed pods
- Then renamed (for some reason) 'Foo' into 'Foo XXX'

The error I was getting **`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code ... /Hassan/Desktop/Foo: no such file ...`**

**Solution**
I just renamed back the folder name to 'Foo' ('Foo XXX' -> 'Foo') and it worked